# The form cannot be displayed in browser because use of session cookies has been disabled in the browser

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am new in SharePoint. I'm receiving the following error while accessing SharePoint online form using c-sharp

"The form cannot be displayed in the browser because the use of session cookies has been disabled in the current browser settings. In order to load the form, session cookies must be allowed."

I also tried with following attempts, but did not found solution.

1. Enabled the session cookie in the browser.
2. Added the httpOnlyCookies tag and set to false in web.config

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, If cookies are enabled, this error may be caused by a hostname with an underscore character (_).

The workaround is to either change the appliance hostname to not have underscore or to use the appliance IP address for accessing the GUI instead of the hostname.

Reference:

https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2013/12/01/sharepoint-and-the-form-cannot-be-displayed-in-the-browser-because-the-use-of-session-cookies-error/

https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/27/the-form-cannot-be-displayed-in-the-browser-because-the-use-of-session-cookies-has-been-disabled-in-the-current-browser-settings-in-order-to-load-the-form-session-cookies-must-be-allowed/

https://analyticaldotnetdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/sharepoint-infopath-form-and-cookies-not-enabled-issue/

Comment: My hostname does not contains ( _ )